# 9-pin micro-d connector for LVDS signals

Tags: connector, signal-integrity, lvds

Has anyone utilized 9-pin micro-d connectors for driving and receiving LVDS signals? I am running the LVDS at 100 Mbps for 20-30 inches.

I am using a vertical pcb mounted connector 380-009-213 from NorComp. Can this connector be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this connector is widely used for Spacewire, which uses LVDS. You should consider using the pinout pairs and shielding defined by the European Cooperation for Space Standardization, ECSS-E-ST-50-12C. The spec is free, but you need to register.

https://ecss.nl/active-standards/engineering/